# C# Rich textbox Append/Delete Question

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I have a rich textbox which contains data loaded in from a database. I want to change the functionality of the rich textbox to ensure that data can only be written to it by a user and not deleted from it.
Of course, making the rich textbox read only won't help, nor will not enabling it. I'm stuck for ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only one RichTextBox, you can't. What you have to do is instead of working with one RichTextBox, you could have two. Use one to show the data from database, and use another with editing enabled for the user to submit new data. something like how forum handle posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the original content loaded from the database displayed in a label and have a separate textbox in which the user can add new content. On save you will concatenate the db content with the text from the textbox and save it back to the DB. This way you can only add and not remove from the original copy.